# Why is ctx.state.user undefined after logging in user when using koa-passport

Tags: passport.js, koa

I am using koa-passport to handle the local signup/login in my react app. I am trying to set up the local authentication without the redirect, since I want to handle routing on the client side.
My Problem: When I send a request to the server after successfully authenticating and logging in a user, I don't have the ctx.state.user object I was hoping to get.
Here is my initial login:

```
router.post('/login/local', passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) // handle error
  else if (!user && info) // handle no user
  else {
    // handle successful login
    ctx.login(user);
  }
}));
```

Then, I want to access the logged in user, like so:

```
router.get('/profile', (ctx) => {
  // ctx.state.user is undefined
}
```

But there is no user property in ctx.state. Isn't this the way this should work or am I missing something?

Comment: `ctx.state` is confined to a single HTTP request. Actually `ctx` is rebuilt for every HTTP request. From the `koa-passport` documentation it seems that you need to call `ctx.isAuthenticated()` in order to find if the user is authenticated (assuming you have the settings correctly setup for a session store). p.s.: You need a session store to preserve the user-state across multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: @zeronone  Thank you, you are right. Though for it turned out the actual issues was that I was using koa-cors, so I needed to allow to send credentials/cookies. Same thing for the ajax call from the client. I wasn't sending the cookie back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
I wasn't sending back the cookies from the client. In my fetch I had to set `credentials: 'include'` to make it work and since I am using koa-cors, I had to specify to allow cookies as well.